# Why are my WINAPI messages not reaching my window procedure?

Tags: c, winapi

I am using a winapi dialog as my root `HWND` for a window class. The program compiles and displays perfectly, but when I click on the buttons, nothing is responsive, almost like the messages aren't reaching my window procedure, or said procedure is never being called. How can I ensure that the messages are working correctly and I'm handling them properly for what I'm trying to do?

Simplified WinMain in main.c:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    static char szAppName[] = TEXT ("AppName"); // Does not display, remove later
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = DlgProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = DLGWINDOWEXTRA;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAIN));
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName  = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MAINMENU);
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
                   TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
                   szAppName,
                   MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), 0, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Simplified `DlgProc` (written in C++ and registered for use in C):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(Message)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            MessageBeep(0); // Does not sound, even if I change the case to WM_CREATE
        break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                // Handle buttons/statics inside the dialog, they do nothing
            }
        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

dialog in resource file:

```
IDD_MAIN DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 207, 156
STYLE WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX
CAPTION "AppTitle"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    // Internal statics and buttons
END
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `hwnd = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MAIN), 0, NULL);` - you forgot to pass your `DlgProc` as the last parameter. (Also, your RegisterClass is pointless. The system provides the dialog class, not you.)

Comment: it's possible to subclass it though

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm testing your `CreateDialog` tip now, but I'm following an example in Programming Windows (Petzold), he doesn't explain his reasoning for registering a window class but I'd assume it's there for a reason?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie could you provide an example of this please? This is probably the route I want to go down.

Comment: @RaymondChen Your solution does work (I just have to change the return type to `BOOL` instead of `LRESULT` which breaks the window class registration, but after deleting the window class it does work as I intended it to!

Comment: @OCDkirby subclassing is changing class of existing window, that's not something to consider at this point. Thing is that you're using `CreateDialog` to create a modeless dialog from resource here and it doesn't use your window class! It creates own, internally, before it calls `CreateWindow`. It's `CreateWindow` what consumes widow class. My only runin with that book (early edition) was in 90s, so I can't say for sure, was that a different code that used CreateWindow?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Nope, he definitely uses `CreateDialog` with a `NULL` dialog procedure argument, I must be missing something where he links up the dialog and the window class. To be specific, I'm using the HEXCALC example as a basis for this program.

Comment: Because you use hexcalc example, add your own dialog template ?

Comment: Also see [Returning values from a dialog procedure](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031107-00/?p=41923).

Comment: @swi You can register a custom window class for a dialog. This is explained in the documentation for [WNDCLASSEXW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw) (`cbWndExtra`). You will have to use the [CLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/class-statement) directive in the resource file to wire things up.

Comment: @IInspectable And indeed, [that's what the program is doing](https://github.com/usr4/hexcalc32/blob/ab11157776b6f560a13161762870712d866925cf/HEXCALC.RC#L20). This is an extremely advanced technique that even I myself (30 years experience) have never needed to do. Not something a beginner should be playing with. Note that your custom dialog window procedure needs to call DefDlgProc or DefWindowProc, since it is now a window procedure, not a dialog procedure.

Comment: @ray Thanks for the confirmation. I'm still struggling to find a use case for this, or even just understand what specific feature a custom window class for a dialog enables, that cannot be done using `CreateDialog` with a custom dialog procedure.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm using it for easy access to brushes, and please add your comment about `CLASS` in the answers because that solved my problem, I'm able to register a window class (and with another two parameters, an extended window class) that corresponds to my dialog perfectly with that addition!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [Using the code](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/tree/master/OneCodeTeam/Windows%20modal%20and%20modeless%20dialogs%20in%20C%2B%2B%20(CppWindowsDialog)#using-the-code) which is in Microsoft GitHub repository steps to complete your program. You should set your dialog `Class Name = AppName` in resource file and Change `WM_INITDIALOG` back to `WM_CREATE` in WndProc that you call `DlgProc`.